# Convert input textfield to plain text and use it as PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to convert an input textfield to plain text and use it as a PHP variable but I don't know how to do it.

Here's my sample code to convert input to plain text:

**HTML**

`<input type="text" id="fileserver"> <button onclick="disable_all();">SUBMIT</button>`

And here's my **JavaScript** code:

```
function disable_all(){ $( "body" ).html($( "#fileserver" ).val()); }
```

Is there any way that I can use the converted text to hold as PHP variable? I hope someone can help me. Thank you so much. :)

**[FIDDLE FOR REFERENCE](http://jsfiddle.net/4P7Wj/1/)**

Comment: Send that to the server using ajax request.

Comment: If you want to use the value of an input field in PHP you either have to submit the form or send the value to the server via ajax

Comment: It could do with a name attribute and be a child of a form element if you go the form submission route.

Comment: @Progrock how can I execute it as a PHP variable if I used it as a form element?

Answer (score 0):

As PHP runs on the server and has finished before the client ( browser ) gets the webpage and because javascript runs in the client ( browser ) you need to send the javascript variable to PHP via some means. You can use a `form submission` - PHP would process the submitted data but this does mean you leave the current thread. The more common way to send data to the backend is via `Ajax` or `Fetch`

The example below sends a simple Ajax request to the same page ( can be any php script not just same page ), does some tasks ( modifies the POST array data here for illustration ) and sends a response which the ajax callback can process.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
        /* Allow PHP to process the request, perform whatever tasks it has to do and then send reply */
        $_POST['time']=time();
        $_POST['date']=date( DATE_ATOM );
        $_POST['ip']=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $_POST['reversed']=strrev( $_POST['fileserver'] );

        exit( json_encode( $_POST ) );
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        <script>
            /* ajax callback - this can do lots more than simply display response in the console. */
            const callback=function( r ){
                console.info( r )
            };

            /* ultra simple ajax function to send a POST request to the same page */
            const ajax=function(data,callback){
                let xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onload=function(){
                    if( this.status==200 && this.readyState==4 )callback( this.response )
                };
                xhr.open( 'POST', location.href, true );
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                xhr.send( data );
            };

            /* invoke the ajax function when the button is pressed */
            const disable_all=function(){
                let data={
                    fileserver:document.querySelector( 'input[ name="fileserver" ]' ).value
                };
                let payload=Object.keys( data ).map( k=>{
                    return [ k, data[ k ] ].join('=')
                })
                ajax( payload, callback ); 
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type='text' name='fileserver' id='fileserver' value='Open the console to view the result' />
        <button onclick='disable_all();'>SUBMIT</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

is this what you mean?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        <script>

            const convert_to_text=function(e){
                let input=document.querySelector( 'input[ name="fileserver" ]' );
                let text=document.createTextNode( input.value );
                input.replaceWith( text );
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type='text' name='fileserver' id='fileserver' />
        <button onclick='convert_to_text()'>Convert</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried to run it in console mode and I've seen the result. BTW, is there any way to convert it into plain text? Just wanna know. Thanks for this btw. ;)

Comment: convert what to plain text?

Comment: the input element

Comment: Sorry - I'm not sure I understand. The input element is `type=text` ~ which is plain text. The value sent by the ajax function is the string value of that field. do you mean that the field is no longer to be an input element but simply text on the webpage?

Comment: What I mean is after I input the value the textbox will disable and it converts into text.